# GestureOverlayView in CoordinatorLayout scroll and NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gesture

how can I put `GestureOverlayView` in my CoordinatorLayout in `NestedScrollView`?
because my problem is that if I draw in `gestureOverlay` scroll even page and the gesture is inusable.

My **activity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewreceipt"
    tools:context=".activities.activity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
                android:id="@+id/activityRecicler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:stackFromEnd="true" />
            <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView 
                android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="#d3d3d3"
                android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
                android:fadeEnabled="false" 
                android:gestureColor="#333"
                android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
                android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
                android:fadeOffset="5000" 
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="testImage" 
                android:text="testami"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab" 
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="#b2d33f"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save_black_36dp"
            android:onClick="saveReceipt" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I draw in vertical in **GestureOverlayView** the entire page scroll and it stops draw.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with a class that extends `NestedScrollView`:

```
public class CustomView extends android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView {
    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.e("enabled", String.valueOf(isEnableScrolling()));
        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the activity implements `GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener`:

```
@Override
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(false);
}

@Override
public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true);
}
```

And in my XML I changed `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` with `CustomView`.